# Linked Lists and fscanf

Tags: c, file, linked-list, scanf

I am trying to create a linked list that will store input from a text file. 
I can get the first set of information but when I come to get succeeding information, I get a seg fault.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Here is my whole code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int CourseID;
    char CourseName[30];
 } courseInfo;

struct StudentInfo{
    char StudentID[9];
    char FirstName[20];
    char LastName[25];
    int Courses;
    courseInfo CourseInfo[10];
    struct StudentInfo *next; 

};
typedef struct StudentInfo studentInfo;
typedef studentInfo *ListPtr;

studentInfo LoadFile(studentInfo *RootPtr);
void PrintStruct(studentInfo *startPtr);

int main()
{
studentInfo studentList[100];
ListPtr HeadPtr = NULL;
printf("Loading File...\n");

LoadFile(HeadPtr);
printf("Load Success\n");
PrintStruct(studentList);
printf("AfterPrint\n");


return 0;
}
studentInfo LoadFile( studentInfo *RootPtr)
{
FILE * ptrFile;

ListPtr NodePtr = malloc(sizeof (studentInfo));
ListPtr curr;
int counter, i=0;


ptrFile = fopen("studentInfo.txt", "r");

if( ptrFile == NULL)
    printf("Open Unsuccessful\n");

fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->StudentID);
printf("%s\n", NodePtr->StudentID);
fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->FirstName);
printf("%s\n", NodePtr->FirstName);
fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->LastName);
printf("%s\n", NodePtr->LastName);
fscanf(ptrFile,"%d", &(NodePtr->Courses));
printf("%d\n", NodePtr->Courses);

for(counter = 0; counter <= NodePtr->Courses; counter++)
{
    fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseName);
    printf("%s ", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseName);
    fscanf(ptrFile,"%d", &(NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseID));
    printf("%d\n", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseID);

}   
curr = RootPtr;
NodePtr->next = NULL;
RootPtr = NodePtr;
NodePtr = NodePtr -> next;

while( strcmp("***", NodePtr->StudentID) !=0 )
{

    fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->StudentID);
    printf("%s\n", NodePtr->StudentID);

    fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->FirstName);
    printf("%s\n", NodePtr->FirstName);

    fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->LastName);
    printf("%s\n", NodePtr->LastName);

    fscanf(ptrFile,"%d", &(NodePtr->Courses));
    printf("%d\n", NodePtr->Courses);

        for(counter = 0; counter <= NodePtr->Courses; counter++)
        {
            fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseName);
            printf("%s ", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseName);
            fscanf(ptrFile,"%d",&(NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseID));
            printf("%d\n", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseID);

        }
    NodePtr = NodePtr->next;
}
fclose(ptrFile);


return *NodePtr;
}
void PrintStruct(studentInfo *startPtr)
 {
int i;
ListPtr begin;
printf("In print\n");
for( begin = startPtr; begin->next != NULL; begin=begin->next)
{
    printf("%s\n", begin->StudentID);
    printf("%s\n", begin->FirstName);
    printf("%s\n", begin->LastName);
    printf("%d\n", begin->Courses);
    for(i = 0; i <= begin->Courses; i++)
    {   
        printf("%s", begin->CourseInfo[i].CourseName);
        printf("%d\n", begin->CourseInfo[i].CourseID);
    }

}

return;
 }
```

`

My text file is : 
111111111
Lisa
Porter
3
ENEE 114
CMSC 412
ENME 515
333333333
Alex
Simpson
1
CMSC 412

---

and will only print up to "333333333"
followed by a '0' and then a seg fault.

Comment: Unrelated: after `printf("Open Unsuccessful\n");` you should exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No limits on string input scanning into inadequate buffer.

The following attempts to store "111111111", into a `char` array.  The first is 9 `char` of which `fscanf(ptrFile,"%s",...)` scans and stores into `NodePtr->StudentID` -  a 9 `char` array.  Then `fscanf` appends a `'\0'` and writes outside the array invoking undefined behavior (UB).

```
struct StudentInfo{
  char StudentID[9];
...
// My text file is : 111111111 Lisa Porter 3 ENEE 114 CMSC 4
fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->StudentID);
```

Code should 1) allocate enough space 2) limit input length with `"%9s"` and 3) check `fscanf()` results.  Better:

```
struct StudentInfo{
  // Enough space for 9 char and \0
  char StudentID[9+1];
...
// add if and ------------v
if (1 != fscanf(ptrFile,"%9s", NodePtr->StudentID)) 
  Handle_Error();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in reading the file, as highlighted by valgrind:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out          
==4662== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4662== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4662== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4662== Command: ./a.out
==4662== 
Loading File...
111111111
Lisa
Porter
3
ENEE 114
CMSC 412
ENME 515
==4662== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4662==    at 0x4E7BA91: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==4662==    by 0x4E855C8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4662==    by 0x400A09: LoadFile (bar.c:66)
==4662==    by 0x400784: main (bar.c:30)
==4662== 
==4662== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4662==    at 0x4E7B0FB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==4662==    by 0x4E7EB02: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==4662==    by 0x4E855C8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4662==    by 0x400A09: LoadFile (bar.c:66)
==4662==    by 0x400784: main (bar.c:30)
==4662== 
==4662== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4662==    at 0x4E7B105: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==4662==    by 0x4E7EB02: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==4662==    by 0x4E855C8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4662==    by 0x400A09: LoadFile (bar.c:66)
==4662==    by 0x400784: main (bar.c:30)
==4662== 
==4662== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4662==    at 0x4E7EB4E: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==4662==    by 0x4E855C8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4662==    by 0x400A09: LoadFile (bar.c:66)
==4662==    by 0x400784: main (bar.c:30)
==4662== 
==4662== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4662==    at 0x4E7BB5C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==4662==    by 0x4E855C8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4662==    by 0x400A09: LoadFile (bar.c:66)
==4662==    by 0x400784: main (bar.c:30)
==4662== 
==4662== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4662==    at 0x4E7BBDF: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1635)
==4662==    by 0x4E855C8: printf (printf.c:33)
==4662==    by 0x400A09: LoadFile (bar.c:66)
==4662==    by 0x400784: main (bar.c:30)
==4662== 
333333333 0
==4662== Invalid read of size 1
==4662==    at 0x4C2D1D3: strcmp (vg_replace_strmem.c:755)
==4662==    by 0x400A5A: LoadFile (bar.c:74)
==4662==    by 0x400784: main (bar.c:30)
==4662==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

More specifically, I suggest that you use `scanf` with `assert` to make sure a value is read (scanf may return without setting the variable if there is nothing to read):

```
    assert(1 == fscanf(ptrFile,"%s", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseName));
    printf("%s ", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseName);
    assert(1 == fscanf(ptrFile,"%d", &(NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseID)));
    printf("%d\n", NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseID);
```

(also, include `assert.h`)

Now, if you execute your program, you'll get:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out           
==4750== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4750== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4750== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4750== Command: ./a.out
==4750== 
Loading File...
111111111
Lisa
Porter
3
ENEE 114
CMSC 412
ENME 515
a.out: bar.c:66: studentInfo LoadFile(studentInfo *): Assertion `1 == fscanf(ptrFile,"%d", &(NodePtr->CourseInfo[counter].CourseID))' failed.
```

So this is indeed the issue: your program tries to read after the end of the file.